# A table and a figure, with captions, in the same wide float in a two-column document?

Tags: floats, two-column

I'm trying to place a figure and a table inside the same wide float so that they are positioned together within a two-column document. However, they also need separate captions (i.e. a figure caption and a table caption).

I tried to wrap the table (`\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}`) and the figure (`\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`) inside a `figure*`, but then I get a compilation error:

```
Float(s) lost.
```

And in the minimal example below, I get

```
LaTeX Error: Not in outer mode
```

as error.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
      stuff
      \caption{abc}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{tabular}
      \begin{table}{c}
        more stuff
      \end{table}
      \caption{abc}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put a `figure` inside a `figure` (or inside a `minipage` even), which is why you are getting floats lost. Just use a figure* on the outside and then use the `caption`  or `capt-of` packages to allow you to go `\captionof{table}{.....}` for the table caption. Don't use `table` or `figure`
environments within the float, just use `\includegraphics` `tabular` etc directly.

Note as it's a `figure*` latex will only ensure that it keeps the right order for the figure. the table may float out of sequence (similarly to using `longtable` or a  `[H]` float from the `float` package). If that does happen you may need to help the ordering by moving tables in the source or adding `\clearpage`.

Comment: Perfect! `capt-of` was just what I needed.