# How to center two custom defined layout elements on a row?

Tags: graphics, positioning

So I am limited via some style doc on how image elements with captions look like:

some code like in here does what they do:

```
\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{%
\abovecaptionskip=-5pt
\belowcaptionskip=-27pt
\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}%
\sbox{\@tempboxa}{{\footnotesize {\textbf{#1.}} #2}}
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa > \hsize
    \begin{center} {\footnotesize {\textbf{#1.}} #2} \par \end{center}
\else
    \global\@minipagefalse
    \hbox to \hsize {\footnotesize \hfil{\textbf{#1.}} #2\hfil}%
\fi
\vspace{\belowcaptionskip}}

\newcommand{\Figure}[3]{\begin{figure}[h]\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}\caption{#3\vspace{ 1cm}}\end{center}\end{figure}}

\newcommand{\WrapFigure}[5]{\begin{wrapfigure}[#1]{l}{#2}
\includegraphics[width=#3]{#4}\caption{#5}
\end{wrapfigure}\vspace{0.3cm}}

\newcommand{\WrapFigureR}[5]{\begin{wrapfigure}[#1]{r}{#2}
\includegraphics[width=#3]{#4}\caption{#5}
\end{wrapfigure}\vspace{0.3cm}}
```

I want to place 2 images with captions like in here:

[image]

I tried this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{array}
\Figure{0.6\textwidth}{d2.eps}{ ~ \label{fig4}} &
\Figure{0.6\textwidth}{d1.eps}{ ~ \label{fig5}} 
\end{array}
\end{center}
```

But failed. So how to make two custom image layout elements live in one row?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46349/a-table-and-a-figure-with-captions-in-the-same-wide-float-in-a-two-column-docu/46350#46350

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use two `minipage`s and the `\captionof` command provided by the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package; the `justification=centering` option will cause each line of the captions to be centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{name1}
\captionof{figure}{A test caption for the first of two figures}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{name2}
\captionof{figure}{A test caption for the second of two figures}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With this approach, the figures won't be treated as a floating object so their placement will be your responsability. If you want the object to be treated as a floating object, simply use `minipage`s inside a `figure` environment and the standard `\caption` command; once again, the `justification=centering` option from the caption package will cause each line of the captions to be centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{name1}
\caption{A test caption for the first of two figures}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{name2}
\caption{A test caption for the second of two figures}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `demo` option for `graphicx` was only used to replace actual images with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual code.